# Spring Boot wait for Elasticsearch to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Boot (2.3) & Elasticsearch (7.14.1) in a Docker setup. I always used `depends_on` in my docker-compose.yml to wait for Elasticsearch before starting the Spring Boot application. (Now as this is removed in docker 3.*!?! this won't work.)

-> **How can I check the availability of Elasticsearch before initializing my Spring Boot application?**

- Can I do this using the Spring-jdbc [DatabaseStartupValidator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/DatabaseStartupValidator.html)?
- Can I do this using Docker health-checks?

FYI: Application works regularly when starting through docker-compose. Spring just fails several times & is restarted until all ES repositories can be initialized.

Comment: It is not an issue in docker compose since your spring app container just gets restarted till it manages to connect to elasticsearch. For production cluster environments you can also depend on `restart-on-failure` or you would be adding readiness probe (i.e in kubernetes deployment file) that will be attempting to connect to elasticsearch.

Comment: I am aware of this. It just pollutes logs a lot and is a common problem if you have multiple services.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to track the readiness of your elasticsearch service **before** starting your application. Example create a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
./wait-for-it.sh -t 10 <your elasticsearch service>:9200
exec <your application>
```

Your Dockerfile may look like:

```
COPY . ./
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-it.sh ./<your bash file>.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./<your bash file>"]
```

Comment: How can I include this into my docker-compose file?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.